# Modfication of single element in list inside function

Tags: python, list, function

I want to change single element of a list by adding "great" before each name of magician without creating new list.

```
magicians = ['john', 'dynamo', 'michael']

def make_great(list_name):
    ['great' + ' ' + magician for magician in list_name]
```

I know where the problem is: this "for in" changes the name of my variable, but do not adds the new one to the list. I tried also by using "while" but with no effect. Output I expect is:

```
magicians = ['great john', 'great dynamo', 'great michael']
```

Comment: all you're missing is the `return` keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
magicians = [ "Great "+ item for item in magicians]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the existing list by updating each member with the new value. The for loop will iterate through each member of the magicians list, and the value of x is used to access each position in the list.

```
magicians = ['john', 'dynamo', 'michael']
x = 0
for magician in magicians:
    magicians[x] = "great {}".format(magician)
    x = x + 1

print(magicians)
```

Comment: you can use `enumerate` for this: `x, magician = enumerate(magicians)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map()` to do this, which is extremely efficient.

```
magicians = ['john', 'dynamo', 'michael']
magicians = list(map(lambda x: "great " + x, magicians)))
```